# Repair 18.04.01 LTS, cloned drive won't boot up

Tags: boot

How do I repair my existing 18.04.01 ubuntu? I've made an installation stick from an 18.04.02 iso hoping to use it to repair but it only offers to install 18.04.02 alongside 18.04.01 or delete it first and then install 18.04.02. I can't find an 18.04.01 iso to download, and even if I did, I'm not sure that would offer me a repair option?

I got here because my hard drive failed (although it would still boot up but then go into read-only mode). I used CloneZilla to clone to a new drive and repair as best it can. The new drive won't boot up, but I can get into grub holding down the shift button.

Comment: To re-install a Ubuntu system using any `ubiquity` installer ISO, (not all Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ISOs use `ubiquity` and you gave too few specifics as to which you're using) use the "Something else", select existing partitions and **do NOT format** any. These selections trigger the *upgrade via re-install* which is the *repair* type of operation; however it doesn't handle 3rd party applications, being only tested/intended for packages found in Ubuntu repositories.  If however you're using a unhealthy drive (ie. one that *flips* to RO mode) you should **not** use this procedure

Comment: You might want to consider https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair